What happened in this battle in Ender's Game?
I read these paragraphs a bunch of times and I cannot figure out what happened. What was Ender's trick, and why was it surprising?

There they were, six small Dragon soldiers down near William Bee's own
door. From the number of lights showing on their flash suits, Bee
could see that three of them were disabled and two of them damaged;
only one was whole. Nothing to be frightened of. Bee casually aimed at
them, pressed the button, and--
Nothing happened.
The lights went on.
The game was over.
Even though he was looking right at them, it took Bee a moment to
realize what had just happened. Four of the Dragon soldiers had their
helmets pressed on the corners of the door. And one of them had just
passed through. They had just carried out the victory ritual. They
were getting destroyed, they had hardly inflicted any casualties, and
they had the gall to perform the victory ritual and end the game right
under their noses.
Only then did it occur to William Bee that not only had Dragon Army
ended the game, it was possible that, under the rules, they had won
it. After all, no matter what happened, you were not certified as the
winner unless you had enough unfrozen soldiers to touch the corners of
the gate and pass someone through into the enemy's corridor.
Therefore, by one way of thinking. you could argue that the ending
ritual was victory. The battleroom certainly recognized it as the end
of the game.

And

Loudly, Anderson said, "After that little maneuver, the rules are
being revised to require that all of the enemy's soldiers must be
frozen or disabled before the gate can be reversed."
"It could only work once anyway," Ender said.

What could only work once?

Basically, the Dragon army claiming victory without actually disabling their opponents. The way the system worked was that, after defeating the opponents, you do the ritual on the gate to win. Despite losing, they did the ritual, and the system marked them as the winners. After this:

"After that little maneuver, the rules are being revised to require that all of the enemy's soldiers must be frozen or disabled before the gate can be reversed."

FWIW, (Spoiler warning) it prefigures his final battle where he realizes that there is

 no way he can win against the enemy forces, so he runs his entire fleet at the planet in a suicide play so that he can fire the device at the planet and claim victory (still thinking it's a simulation, of course). Since the victory condition is not actually winning the fight, but taking the planet, that's what he did.


I'm still confused. Wasn't the point of the battle to defeat the enemy's gate, like Capture the Flag?

@TheAsh: Yes, and the idea is that you can't do so without defeating all of the enemies first, but that's not how they actually programmed it. To some degree, Ender used something like a speedrunning trick in video games. Normally, in a boss battle, after defeating them, you get the button to press to end the level. Instead, he went right to the button and pressed it, so to speak.

:) Or like Torg in https://static.sluggy.com/comics/900/020915b6-1.png

I think the point is that every kid is told that to win you defeat the enemy army. That's how it's always been played. No one challenged the assumption that the actual win condition was different, plus it would be hard to capture the enemy gate without defeating all of the enemy soldiers first. It took even the most brilliant kids being pushed to despair under the weight of adult expectations to see the game for what it is, rather than what they've been told.

If you're told that the game is Team Slayer, and that everyone has always been playing Team Slayer, it's understandable to not realize that the silly flag bit at the end means you've been playing Capture the Flag all along.

Like Miles said: "I've known people who play chess like this. They can't think their way to a checkmate, so they spend their time trying to clear the board of the little pieces. This eventually reduces the game to a simplicity they can grasp, and they're happy. The perfect war is a fool's mate."

@FuzzyBoots I thought Sluggy Freelance had died the death years ago. I guess I have a decade's worth to catch up on

@Separatrix: I stopped reading around the same time, I think. Somewhere in the epic gods tales, I just felt like either it had lost the plot, or I had.

Ender was placed in an escape room, and told to escape. Most people go through all of the puzzles. Ender just goes through the fire exit.

Ender subverted Bee's expectations. Bee assumed that the true win condition wasn't merely the "victory ritual", but that the other army must be completely disabled first. That wasn't the case, and Ender's strategy was to perform the actual win condition: the victory ritual.
It was a cheap trick that no army would ever fall for again. In the future armies would surely guard their own gate to prevent this from happening, had Anderson not changed the rules to make the implicit victory condition an explicit victory condition. Thus Ender's comment: "it could only work once anyway."
